# Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application on dev azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I have an issue at PowerShell script for executing on pipeline at dev azure,
error is happening with message:
*Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application*

it was worked some time ago but now it is not, is it some updates were done on azure?
or I need to improve some code?

```
 foreach ($alert in $alerts)
    {
        Write-Log "`tCreating alert $($alert.AlertName)"
        $azArgs = "monitor metrics alert create --name ""$($alert.AlertName)"" --resource-group ""$($resourceGroup)"" --condition ""$($alert.AlertRule)"" --scopes ""$($alert.ResourceId)"" --window-size 5m --evaluation-frequency 1m --action ""$actionGroupResourceId"" --description "" "" --subscription ""$subscriptionId"" --auto-mitigate true"
        Write-Verbose $azArgs
        Start-Process "az" -ArgumentList $azArgs -NoNewWindow -Wait
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is related to azure updates https://pullanswer.com/questions/error-with-startprocess-and-az-command

problem is Azure Cli has been updated and so now there is an az.ps1 so i need to make "az.cmd" in order to continue to call the good program...

Answer (score 1):

> *Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application*

AFAIK, the issue shows that you are not using X32 environment. so, that the error thrown. It is a common issue we cannot directly find out what exactly happens we can fix it by following

#### Ways to fix:

1. Try to uninstall and install the **PowerShell Az module**.
2. Update the **PowerShell Az module** with latest version
3. Check your Dev environment has X64. If it is X64 make sure to install the **PowerShell Module** Globally.
4. It may happen sometimes with you are passing environment variable path make sure to double check once.